# the purpose of [0] in data visualisation syntax

Tags: data-visualization

in this code :
plt.scatter(train.ENGINESIZE, train.CO2EMISSIONS,  color='blue')
plt.plot(train_x, regr.coef_[0][0]*train_x + regr.intercept_[0], '-r')

what is the purpose of this term : [0] ?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at [sklearn docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html), they usually have something like

> **intercept_** float or array of shape (n_targets,)
>   Independent term in the linear model. Set to 0.0 if fit_intercept = False.

So for multiple regression, the return values are higher dimensional, and the `[0]` indicates the first entry.